# What is Music.SE, and what is its relationship to Musical Practice & Performance?

Tags: discussion

I've heard the term bandied about, but I don't understand what StackExchange is planning.

Comment: Music.SE is generally short for Musical Practice & Performance AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

StackExchange websites can be referred to in shorthand by the URL subdomain.

Musical Practice & Performance Stack Exchange has a url of http://**music**.stackexchange.com/, therefore, you can refer to it as Music.SE.

The same applies to Audio-Video Production as AVP.SE, Geographic Information Systems as GIS.SE, and English Language & Usage as English.SE.

Comment: Additionally, you can reference sites with links in comments by using the shorthand of `[music.SE]`, which results in [Music.SE]. See more comment shorthand [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Wow! I wish I'd have seen that a long time ago. I've picked up bits and pieces, but I never knew you could find them all in one place. Thanks!